# Source SDK Compile Errors

Tags: c++

I am making a Counter Strike mod and during compiling I am getting some errors:

```
Panel.cpp(715): error C2248: 'CInput::CVerifiedUserCmd' : cannot access private class declared in class 'CInput'
1>          \SDK\\game\\client\\input.h(238) : see declaration of 'CInput::CVerifiedUserCmd'
1>          \SDK\\game\\client\\input.h(39) : see declaration of 'CInput'
```

Line 715:

```
CInput::CVerifiedUserCmd* ver = NULL;
```

Declaration:

```
class CVerifiedUserCmd
{
public:
    CUserCmd    m_cmd;
    CRC32_t     m_crc;
};
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: There's by far not enough context in this question to allow for a meaningful answer, other than "figure out what you did wrong and fix it".

Comment: Can you post `CInput` class declaration?

Comment: CInput Declaration:

http://pastebin.com/79NJR2NG

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: C++ doesn't have "inner" classes, but it does look like a nested class.

Comment: `CVerifiedUserCmd` is declared in `private` section of `CInput`. You can't access it as it is currently implemented.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably trying to use a `private` inner class:

```
class A
{
   class B
   {
   };
};
```

Simply make the class `public` if you wish to use it outside:

```
class A
{
public:
   class B
   {
   };
};
```

EDIT:

If the class is private and it's part of a 3rd party lib, you're probably doing it wrong. Look for a different solution to your problem, it was made private for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that was your code put class

```
CVerifiedUserCmd
```

to public section of the outer class. Otherwise you cannot use CVerifiedUserCmd since it is private inner class.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't (unless you want to edit the engine itself) - look for a better solution to your problem. Basically, don't try to manually instantiate `CInput::CVerifiedUserCmd`.